# Perfino GC Activity Always 0%

Tags: perfino

Have noticed that across all our monitored VMs, the Perfino GC Activity telemetry is always 0% and the graph is flat.

The rest of the built-in telemetries like heap usage and CPU utlisation work OK.

Is there something we need to turn on so that Perfino collects GC Activity?

We're using Perfino version 4.0.4 (build 4037).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the GC telemetry that will be fixed in 4.0.5. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.